# Absolute element's position in presence of virtual keyboard in iphone

Tags: javascript, ios, css, iphone, mobile-safari

I have a chatting application page in my website. The main container takes full height and width on mobile devices. The container has `position: fixed` and 3 parts inside it have `position:absolute`. The last div `#app-msg-composer` has a `textarea` and send `button` inside it like other chat applications. Below is the css:

```
#app-container{
    position: fixed;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    top: 0px;
    bottom:0px;
}
#app-header{
    position:absolute;
    height:48px;
    width:100%;
    top:0px;
}
#app-body{
    position:absolute;
    top:48px;
    bottom: 74px;
    width:100%;
}
#app-msg-composer{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0px;
    height:74px;
    width:100%;
}
```

This works fine in android devices but in iPhone whenever the virtual keyboard is opened to type a message half of the screen is scrolled up out of the viewport. Also the `#app-msg-composer` is visible at the correct position but when I inspect it(in the iphone), it is aligned to the bottom(behind virtual keyboard) due to which I am unable to click on send button. Then when I scroll the page everything comes to it's place. These issues occur only when virtual keyboard is on in iPhone.

To summarise, `position:absolute` elements inside `position: fixed` elements take their `top` and `bottom` **relative to browser window** and not the parent when virtual keyboard is active.

I tried some solutions from stackoverflow but did not work. How to do this in javascript or css only as I am not using any library?

Comment: Have you managed to figure this out? Bump. Encountering the same issue.